# how to do user performance test on solidity code?

Tags: performance, testing, ethereum, solidity

I'm writing a thesis about a project written by solidity. I wants to add some content about user performance test of my code. I have thought abou calculating the excuting time of every funciton but I found that almost meaningless. Are there any good idea to apply user performance test on solidity code(smart contracts)?

Answer (score 1):

> I wants to add some content about user performance test of my code

There is no point to do performance tests in Solidity, because this metric is irrelevant. Users are not going to run you Solidity code. I suggest first study deeper how blockchains work.